# Button not firing inside Accordion Panes inside which is inside Update Panel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am customizing one website but , while using triggers in update panel the click event is not firing.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True"
```

Also see the `Content Template`

```
<ContentTemplate>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <cc1:accordion id="Accordion1" runat="server" headercssclass="headeraccordian">
<panes>
          <cc1:accordionpane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
      <header>
           <a href="#">
             <asp:Label ID="dailyreport" CssClass="lbl" runat="server" Text="Daily Report"></asp:Label></a>
     </header>
   <content>
          <div>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="94px"></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:Button ID="btnCal" runat="server" Text="Select Date" OnClick="btnCal_Click" />
             &nbsp;
              <asp:Button ID="btnDownLoads" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="btnDownLoads_Click" />
            <asp:Calendar ID="cal" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="cal_SelectionChanged" BackColor="White"
                 BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black"
                 Height="190px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" Width="350px">
                 <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
                 <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
                <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4px" Font-Bold="True"
                Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" />
           </asp:Calendar>
        </div>
 </content>
        </cc1:accordionpane>
</panes>
</cc1:accordion>
               </td>
             </tr>
        </table> </ContentTemplate>
```

Also see the triggers

Also see the code-behind for the button click:-

```
protected void btnDownLoads_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string wdr = "dR";
        string value = txtDate.Text;
        string str = wdr + value;
        string foldername = "Daily";
        string filename = str + ".pdf";
        var filePath = Path.Combine(@"D:\REPORTS\" + foldername + " ", filename);
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Response.ContentType = @"application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader(
            @"Content-Disposition",
            @"attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            Response.WriteFile(filePath);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('No report uploaded for this date')</script>");
        }
    }
```

I just want click event to be fired on click, and it is .............

but `Response.End()` function is not working properly while downloading the file.

See the `page_load` code;-

```
try
    {
        this.SmartNavigation = true;
        if (this.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            //FillReport();
            txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            cal.Visible = false;
            currentdate.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToLongDateString();

            #region edited 
            #region download click

            checkdailydata();

            #endregion
            #endregion
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ext) // Edited Jimit included try catch
    {
        CreateLogFiles ls = new CreateLogFiles();
        ls.ErrorLog(Server.MapPath(@"~\ErrorLog\ErrorMsg"), ext.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean the file isn't transferred to the client side after the button click event??

Comment: @Mr.香港人: Yes, on button click nothing is happening

Comment: Because the update panel stopped the file from transferring to the client side, try to remove the update panel, see if it works..

Comment: @Mr.香港人: I tried that, still nothing is happening

Comment: Then try response.transmitfile instead of WriteFile

Comment: ok let me check will let you know..!!

Comment: @Mr.香港人:  no it is not working..!!

Comment: I tried creating a new project with code in this link: http://ideone.com/MKmHPt and it's working, maybe you'll have to post the code on page_Load or page_Init.

Comment: also add a try catch block on the button click event, maybe there're exceptions thrown..

Comment: @Mr.香港人: Sorry for late reply, Error is: `Error on Response.End() in a catch is:

ExceptionState = Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same issue long time back

Try Removing the `Trigger` on .aspx page and add(Registered Control) like below code on *page_load* outside *!page.isPostback{})*

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btnDownLoads);
```

See whether it works or not